# finding start and end date for 2 conditions

Tags: php

Basically, my question is about finding date-ranges

From today's date [ using **date()** ], I want to find

1. starting and ending date for current week

   ```
   Let's assume
   Today: 14 July, 2011
   start of week: 10 July, 2011
   end of week: 16 July, 2011
   ```
2. starting and ending date for current month

   ```
   Let's assume
   Today: 14 July, 2011
   start of month: 1 July, 2011
   end of month: 31 July, 2011
   ```

How can I find these dates ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$firstOfTheMonth = date('1 F Y');
$lastOfTheMonth  = date('t F Y');

$startOfTheWeek  = date('j F Y', mktime(0, 0, 0, date('n'), date('j') - date('w')));
$endOfTheWeek    = date('j F Y', mktime(0, 0, 0, date('n'), date('j') - date('w') + 6));
```

All the [different parameters for `date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) basically give you all you need, the rest is a tiny bit of math.